Pip download `Cannot Install` Due To Conflict While Showing Exact Version Match?
Description
I'm attempting to run pip download in order to bundle wheels into a zip file to upload to a service without internet access. I need to download all of my dependencies from PyPI and then upload them to the service for the service to run.
While running pip download I hit this error which makes very little sense to me due to the constraint message exactly matching on the version. Particularly since the constraint  uses ==.
Here's the constraint file used
Error
 python -m pip download -r requirements/requirements.txt -d plugins
Looking in links: /usr/local/airflow/plugins
WARNING: Location '/usr/local/airflow/plugins' is ignored: it is either a non-existing path or lacks a specific scheme.
ERROR: Cannot install apache-airflow-providers-amazon==8.16.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested apache-airflow-providers-amazon==8.16.0
    The user requested (constraint) apache-airflow-providers-amazon==8.16.0

To fix this you could try to:
 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict


requirements.txt
--constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.8.1/constraints-3.11.txt"

apache-airflow-providers-amazon==8.16.0
apache-airflow-providers-postgres==5.10.0

#       https://seasensor.atlassian.net/browse/SP-4980
--find-links /usr/local/airflow/plugins --no-index

# TODO: Remove these dependencies when we've moved to remote operators. These
#       are all Task Code Requirements and not Airflow Requirements
# NOTE: Any requirement found both in https://github.com/iocurrents/data-pipeline/blob/main/scripts/requirements.txt
#       and in the constraints file automatically default to the constrains file
#       version.
botocore==1.34.67
iniconfig==2.0.0
jmespath==1.0.1
jsonschema==4.21.1
jsonschema-specifications==2023.12.1
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
mdurl==0.1.2
numpy==1.24.4  # Downgraded from 1.24.4
packaging==24.0
pandas==2.1.4 # Downgraded from 2.2.1
pluggy==1.3.0  # Downgrade from 1.4.0
psycopg2==2.9.9
pygments==2.17.2
pytest==7.4.4  # Downgraded from 8.1.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2  # Downgraded from 2.9.0.post0
pytz==2023.3.1.1  # Downgraded from 2024.1
referencing==0.32.1  # Downgraded from 0.34.0
rich==13.7.0  # Downgraded from 13.7.1
rpds-py==0.17.1 # Downgraded from 0.18.0
s3transfer==0.8.2 # Downgraded from 0.10.1
six==1.16.0
tzdata==2023.4 # Downgraded from 2024.1
urllib3==2.0.7 # Upgraded from 1.25.4

Environment Information
python --version
Python 3.11.9
python -m pip --version
pip 24.0 from /Users/alexlordthorsen/.venvs/package_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

Removing The Version Pin Doesn't Work
python -m pip download -r requirements/requirements.txt -d plugins
Looking in links: /usr/local/airflow/plugins
WARNING: Location '/usr/local/airflow/plugins' is ignored: it is either a non-existing path or lacks a specific scheme.
ERROR: Cannot install apache-airflow-providers-amazon because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested apache-airflow-providers-amazon
    The user requested (constraint) apache-airflow-providers-amazon==8.16.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts

Edit:
Commenting out the line
--find-links /usr/local/airflow/plugins --no-index

seems to have removed the issue in terms of being able to download requirements but it also means that my target system will not find the bundled zip file that contains all of the wheels.
